# Javascript Display Total Value of Checkboxes Checked Unless Value Greater Than Amount

Tags: javascript

I have a set of checkboxes where if a user checks one of them then the total value is updated with the amount.

I need to adjust it so that if the user selects enough checkboxes where the value is greater than a set amount, say $60,000, it displays the text "$60,000+" instead of the actual total number.

I made a codepen with the code I am using. Im not sure how to get the logic right so it shows only if the value is greater than when the value is a variable.

Any help is great. Thanks!!

https://codepen.io/nickportify/pen/qBmovQr

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total = document.getElementById('payment-total');

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
      var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
      total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
      var new_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input111').value);
      console.log(new_total);
      document.getElementById('input111').value = new_total + add
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="card-title questionasa1 wgyyybb">Right now if you select a checkbox the value at the bottom updates with the total value of the checkboxes you select.
  <br>
  <br> I'm trying to make it so that if a user selects multiple checkboxes and the total is over £60,000 than instead of displaying the total it displays the text "£60,000+"
  <br>
  <br> I'd also like the total to include commas so it can display "£4,000" for example instead of "£4000".<br>

  <br>
  <hr>
  <p class="card-text questionasubbb geeedffd">Select all that apply.</p>


  <div class="inputcheck2 form-group">
    <div class="btn-group2z" role="group" aria-label="Basic check toggle button group">


      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-2-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="45000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-2-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="home-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="home outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a mortgage     
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-21-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="3000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-21-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="car-sport-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="car-sport-outline
"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a car loan     
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-22-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="1000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-22-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="card-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="card outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a credit card
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-23-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="500">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-23-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="cash-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="cash outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a personal loan
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-24-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="45000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-24-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="speedometer-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="speedometer outline"></ion-icon>
                I'm new to credit and trying to build my credit score
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-25-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="50000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-25-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="trending-up-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="trending up outline"></ion-icon>
               I'm not sure yet! Just preparing for the future.
        </label>
      </div>




      <br>
      <hr>
      <p class="card-text partfofo mt-3">
        <input id="input111" type="text" value="0" style="display:none;" /> Based on your reasons for building credit, having an excellent score could save you up to
        <span id="bigliner1">£<span id="payment-total">0</span></span>* on interest and fees.






    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be where You have two different variables.
One which has the **actual numeric value** and another which has the value you **display**.

```js
 window.onload=function(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');
var totalElement = document.getElementById('payment-total');
var totalValue = parseFloat(totalElement.innerHTML);          
var totalActualValue = totalValue;
          
 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
     var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
      totalValue = totalValue + add;
      totalActualValue = totalValue;
      if(totalActualValue > 65000){
      totalElement.innerHTML = '65000+'
      }
      else 
        totalElement.innerHTML = totalActualValue;
      
        var new_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input111').value);
      console.log(new_total);
        document.getElementById('input111').value=new_total + add
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    
            
                    <h5 class="card-title questionasa1 wgyyybb">Right now if you select a checkbox the value at the bottom updates with the total value of the checkboxes you select. 
                      <br>
                                            <br> 

                      I'm trying to make it so that if a user selects multiple checkboxes and the total is over £60,000 than instead of displaying the total it displays the text "£60,000+"   
                      <br>
                      <br> 
                      I'd also like the total to include commas so it can display "£4,000" for example instead of "£4000".<br> 

                      <br> 
                      <hr> 
                    <p class="card-text questionasubbb geeedffd">Select all that apply.</p>


            <div class="inputcheck2 form-group">
                      <div class="btn-group2z" role="group" aria-label="Basic check toggle button group">
                          
                          
<div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-2-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="45000" >
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-2-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="home-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="home outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a mortgage     
        </label>
</div>
                          
<div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-21-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="3000"  >
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-21-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="car-sport-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="car-sport-outline
"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a car loan     
        </label>
</div>
                          
<div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-22-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="1000" >
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-22-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="card-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="card outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a credit card
        </label>
</div>                          
                          
<div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-23-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="500" >
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-23-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="cash-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="cash outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a personal loan
        </label>
</div>                          
                          
<div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox"  name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-24-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="45000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-24-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="speedometer-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="speedometer outline"></ion-icon>
                I'm new to credit and trying to build my credit score
        </label>
</div>                          
                          
<div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-25-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="50000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-25-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="trending-up-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="trending up outline"></ion-icon>
               I'm not sure yet! Just preparing for the future.
        </label>
</div>                          
                          
                          
                          
                          
                 <br> 
                          <hr> 
   <p class="card-text partfofo mt-3">
<input id="input111" type="text" value="0" style="display:none;"/>
                        Based on your reasons for building credit, having an excellent score could save you up to 
                        <span id="bigliner1">£<span id="payment-total">0</span></span>* on interest and fees.

     
                          
                          
                          
                          
                </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you just create one listener, which catches all `change` events, and which then sums up all checked inputs from scratch. I removed the `input111`, as I don't think you need that with this solution:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
        total = document.getElementById('payment-total');

    document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let input of inputs) {
            sum += input.value * input.checked;
        }
        total.textContent = sum > 65000 ? "65000+" : sum;
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="card-title questionasa1 wgyyybb">Right now if you select a checkbox the value at the bottom updates with the total value of the checkboxes you select.
  <br>
  <br> I'm trying to make it so that if a user selects multiple checkboxes and the total is over £60,000 than instead of displaying the total it displays the text "£60,000+"
  <br>
  <br> I'd also like the total to include commas so it can display "£4,000" for example instead of "£4000".<br>

  <br>
  <hr>
  <p class="card-text questionasubbb geeedffd">Select all that apply.</p>


  <div class="inputcheck2 form-group">
    <div class="btn-group2z" role="group" aria-label="Basic check toggle button group">


      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-2-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="45000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-2-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="home-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="home outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a mortgage     
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-21-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="3000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-21-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="car-sport-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="car-sport-outline
"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a car loan     
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-22-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="1000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-22-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="card-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="card outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a credit card
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-23-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="500">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-23-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="cash-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="cash outline"></ion-icon>
                I want to get a personal loan
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-24-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="45000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-24-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="speedometer-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="speedometer outline"></ion-icon>
                I'm new to credit and trying to build my credit score
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="myCheckBox btn-check sum" id="btn-check-25-outlined" autocomplete="off" value="50000">
        <label class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-outline-primary" name="colorCheckbox" for="btn-check-25-outlined">
            <ion-icon name="trending-up-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="trending up outline"></ion-icon>
               I'm not sure yet! Just preparing for the future.
        </label>
      </div>




      <br>
      <hr>
      <p class="card-text partfofo mt-3">
        Based on your reasons for building credit, having an excellent score could save you up to
        <span id="bigliner1">£<span id="payment-total">0</span></span>* on interest and fees.






    </div>
  </div>
```